# Java:Show message dialog for 10sec and remove?

Tags: java, swing

Hi i want to show `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Appication already running");`

for 10sec and then remove it.how can i dothat?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a JOptionPane manually, without static methods:

```
JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane("Your message", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(parent, "Title");
```

then you can show the dialog and fire up a timer to hide it after ten seconds.

Comment: What's the parent paremeter?

Comment: @MarkSantos parentComponent – determines the frame in which the dialog is displayed; if the parentComponent has no Frame, a default Frame is used

Answer (score 9):

I tried these answers and ran into the problem that showing the dialog is a blocking call, so a timer can't work. The following gets around this problem.

```
      JOptionPane opt = new JOptionPane("Application already running", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, null, new Object[]{}); // no buttons
  final JDialog dlg = opt.createDialog("Error");
  new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
          public void run()
          {
            try
            {
              Thread.sleep(10000);
              dlg.dispose();

            }
            catch ( Throwable th )
            {
              tracea("setValidComboIndex(): error :\n"
                  + cThrowable.getStackTrace(th));
            }
          }
        }).start();
  dlg.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

My Java is a bit rusty but you should be able to just use the standard `Timer` class:

```
import java.util.Timer;

int timeout_ms = 10000;//10 * 1000
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new CloseDialogTask(), timeout_ms);

//implement your CloseDialogTask:

class CloseDialogTask extends TimerTask {
  public void run() {
    //close dialog code goes here
  }
}
```

Comment: with swing, it is preferable to use javax.swing.Timer instead of this one.

Answer (score 1):

```
// =====================
// yes = 0, no = 1, cancel = 2 
// timer = uninitializedValue, [x] = null  

public static void DialogBox() {

    JOptionPane MsgBox = new JOptionPane("Continue?", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);
    JDialog dlg = MsgBox.createDialog("Select Yes or No");
    dlg.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    dlg.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
      @Override
      // =====================
      public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
      // =====================
        super.componentShown(e);
        Timer t; t = new Timer(7000, new ActionListener() {
          @Override
          // =====================
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          // =====================
            dlg.setVisible(false);
          }
        });
        t.setRepeats(false);
        t.start();
      }
    });
    dlg.setVisible(true);
    Object n = MsgBox.getValue();
    System.out.println(n);
    System.out.println("Finished");
    dlg.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: This might solve the problem, but you should explain how and why this solves it, not just code.

Answer (score 0):

make small frame like JOptionPane , show it in thread and dispose after 10 sec